# Android: how do I set a SharedPreferences counter to a RecyclerView TextView?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-recyclerview

I have an Activity where a button click saves a bundle of user input data to a SQLite database that then populates a CardView in a RecyclerView list.  I'd like to create a counter that starts with a default value of zero and increments by +1 each time the "Save" button is clicked (a new CardView is created) and then output that counter onto the CardView in the RecyclerView list.

I am getting and Android Studio error in the Adapter file in the OnBindViewHolder method, in the last line where it starts "holder..."  How would I get the Context from the Activity to the Adapter file?  I thought getSharedPreferences() allowed global Context whereas getPreferences() would not work.

I set up the counter using SharedPreferences in the Activity file with the button click:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    public void onClickSave(View v) {
    ...
    int totalcount = 0;
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Share_Prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("int_key", ++totalcount);
    editor.apply();
```

The RecyclerView Adapter file has the following code:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ListViewHolder> {
    ....
    Context context;
    ....
    public Adapter(Context context, List<UserData> dbList) {
    this.context =  context;

    public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView cardBlankTextNums; 

        public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardBlankTextNums = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardBlankTextNums);

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return dbList.size();
        }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    int totalcount = 0;

    holder.cardBlankTextNums.setText(dbList.get(position).getSharedPreferences.edit.getInt("int_key",totalcount));
```

Comment: dbList.get(position).getSharedPreferences... the syntax is incorrect

Comment: Ok any thoughts on the correct syntax?

Comment: I'll post an answer below

Answer (score 0):

`getSharedPreferences` works on a `Context` and since your adapter doesn't have one, the name cannot be resolved so you need to pass the context to your adapter class some how. It is the best to do it in the constructor:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ListViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;

    public Adapter (Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    ...

public void onBindViewHolder(final ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.cardBlankTextNums.setText(mContext.getSharedPreferences("Share_Prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("int_key",totalcount));
```

And when you want to instantiate a new Adapter you need to pass the context. For example if you are in the activity you need to do:

```
Adapter newAdapter = new Adapter(this);
```

If you are in a fragment you need to do:

```
Adapter newAdapter = new Adapter(getActivity());
```

Comment: So the setText doesn't need the CardView position using "dbList.get(position)..."?

Comment: @AJW personally I'm not sure what logic are you using but, getSharedPreferences returns a fixed number regardless of the position of your views

Comment: I did pass the context, I forgot to include.  I will edit the above code to show.

Comment: @AJW you need to call context.getSharedPreferences(...) anyway

Comment: Ok, I updated the holder to include the context code you suggested.  All looks goods now except "totalcount".  I assume I need to set an int variable for that?

Comment: holder.cardBlankTextNums.setText(Integer.toString(mContext.getSharedPreferences("Share_Prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("int_key",totalcount)));

Comment: Ok Android Studio warning message about not using Number#toString() but rather use String.format.  Would Integer.parseInt be helpful?

Comment: Ok I will give it a try.

Comment: Ok the first TextView populates with "1" for the first CardView as expected.  But the counter is not working as the next CardView also shows a "1".  I had to add "int total count = 0;" in OnBindViewHolder.

Comment: @AJW what you want to achieve is quite hard to do with this logic

Comment: Ok any ideas on how to re-arrange the logic to make it easier?